# Displaying BitmapField in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am not sure why but I am not able to display a bitmapField in my blackberry application. The bitmap never renders.

Here is the code: The image is placed in the res folder:

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BitmapField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

/**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
 * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
 */
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen
{
    BitmapField bitmapField;

    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public MyScreen()
    {        
        Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("res/apresslogo.png");
        bitmapField = new BitmapField(logoBitmap,Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
        add(bitmapField); 
        // Set the displayed title of the screen       
        setTitle("MyTitle");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing just the filename, without a path:

```
Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("apresslogo.png");
```